# Symfony Model is returning null instead of class

Tags: php, symfony

When I attempt to load my database results, it doesn't work, until I switch:

```
$id === null
```

to

```
$id !== null
```

.. then, everything loads as expected.  What am I missing?

Here's my code:

config.php

```
'services' => array(
   'models' =>  array(
       'serv.widget.model.widget' => array(
             'class' => 'ServPlugin\BundleNameBundle\Model\ClassModel'
          )
   )
  ),
```

DefaultController.php

```
namespace ServPlugin\BundleNameBundle\Controller;
use Serv\CoreBundle\Controller\FormController;
use ServPlugin\BundleNameBundle\Entity\Class;

    /** @var \ServPlugin\BundleNameBundle\Model\ClassModel $classModel */
    $classModel = $this->getModel('class');
    /** @var \ServPlugin\BundleNameBundle\Entity\Class $class */
    $class = $classModel->getEntity($formId);

//html here
echo 'Total Rows: '.$class->getCount();
```

ClassModel.php

```
namespace ServPlugin\BundleNameBundleBundle\Model;
use Serv\CoreBundle\Model\FormModel;
use ServPlugin\BundleNameBundleBundle\Entity\Class;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException;

class ClassModel extends FormModel
{

public function getEntity($id = null)
{
    if ($id === null) {
        return new Class();
    }

    return parent::getEntity($id);
}
```

function getEntity is what I am struggling with.
When I view the cache, I can see the model is loading appropriately, but I cannot access it until I go backwards on the null value.

(It turns out, $classModel is loading nothing; -- so when my code moves to $class->getCount() -- the $formId is working as it should (which is a number); the model should be loading FIRST with ServPlugin\BundleNameBundle\Model\ClassModel with ID #7, right?)

This is the error I get when I try to call it as posted above:

> Call to a member function getCount() on null - in file /var/www/plugins/BundleNameBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php - at line 299 [] []

Line 299:
    $class->getCount()

Comment: Clearly $formId has a value besides null.  Perhaps 0?

Comment: Correct, $formId has a value (as it should).  However, it's not grabbing the model because for some reason, $classModel is turning up null.

Comment: If you say so.  Consider following the Symfony framework approach and then adjusting it to suit your needs.  I'm guessing the code in your question does not reflect your actual code so it is hard to offer more concrete suggestions.

Comment: var_dump($formId) = string(1) "7"  

$formId is used for another class (that works fine), but for some reason or another, this particular model class turns up blank.